# Heroku + rails + svelte deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, svelte

I have been trying to develop a Rails + svelte project, but when I deploy to Heroku styles in the svelte component are not being compiled. It works fine in development. To make it work I had to add this to my enviroment.js:

```
let getSvelteEnvironments
try {
  getSvelteEnvironments = require('svelte_ujs_ng/getSvelteEnvironments')
} catch(e) {
  if (e.code !== 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND') {
    throw e;
  }
  getSvelteEnvironments = require('svelte_ujs_ng/svelte_ujs/getSvelteEnvironments')
}
```

I'm using svelte-react gem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by changing:

/config/webpack/loaders/svelte.js
emitCss: false

I'm not sure that this is what I want, as the documentation says this might impact performance, so if anyone has a better approach, it would be great.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).